# How to get a column value based on adjacent column value in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I want to fetch a column value based on the next column value.i'm grepping for a column having value host and want to print the previous column value

tried using `grep -Po ".* (?=host)"` but didn't get the proper output

file `test.log` contains below sample data(all in a single row)

```
test Plus 193310 68FAD575EC59C2C6 exa4dbadm03  host
```

```
cat test.log|grep -i 193310|grep -i host|grep -Po ".* (?=host)"
```

I'm trying to grep the column which having value as host and print the previous column value.  In this case i want to get `exa4dbadm03` as a output

**expected result:**
exa4dbadm03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this? E.g:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i){if($i=="host"){print $(i-1);break}}}' file
```